# Get data from webpage via Apple script

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get the data of Crypto name, Price, and % from the webpage https://www.worldcoinindex.com/

How can i get the % column value via the following scripts?

```
set theHtml to do shell script "curl -s " & quoted form of "https://www.worldcoinindex.com"
set text item delimiters to {"<tbody>", "</tbody>"}
set tableContents to theHtml's text item 2 # item 2 is the body of the price table
set text item delimiters to {"<h2>"} # site uses new h2 for each currency
set tableChunks to tableContents's text items 2 thru -1
set pasteStr to ""
repeat with aChunk in tableChunks
    set text item delimiters to "><span>$ </span><span class=\"span\">"
    tell aChunk's text item 1 to set {theSymbol, thePrice} to {first word, last word}
    set pasteStr to pasteStr & theSymbol & tab & thePrice & return
end repeat
set the clipboard to pasteStr
```

Comment: Kudos for what you have so far. Can you use the classname of `percentage` in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate way for your consideration:

Note that this requires **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be checked on the hidden **Develop** menu in **Safari**.

To unhide the hidden **Develop** menu:

- **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** > **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar**

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    
    make new document ¬
        with properties {URL:"https://www.worldcoinindex.com"}
    
    my waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    
    tell front document
        
        set tickerList to {}
        set lastPriceList to {}
        set percentageList to {}
        
        repeat with i from 0 to 99
            set ticker to ¬
                do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ticker')[" & i & "].innerText;"
            copy words of ticker as text to end of tickerList
            set lastPrice to ¬
                do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('number pricekoers lastprice')[" & i & "].innerText;"
            copy lastPrice to end of lastPriceList
            
            set percentage to ¬
                do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('percentage')[" & i & "].innerText;"
            copy percentage to end of percentageList
        end repeat
        
    end tell
    
end tell

set tempListItem to {}
set groupedItemsList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    copy item i of tickerList to end of tempListItem
    copy item i of lastPriceList to end of tempListItem
    copy item i of percentageList to end of tempListItem
    copy tempListItem to end of groupedItemsList
    set tempListItem to {}
end repeat

set tabDelimitatedListAsText to ""
repeat with anItem in groupedItemsList
    set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
        {AppleScript's text item delimiters, tab}
    set thisItem to text of anItem as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    set tabDelimitatedListAsText to ¬
        tabDelimitatedListAsText & thisItem & linefeed
end repeat

set the clipboard to tabDelimitatedListAsText


on waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Wait for page to finish loading in Safari.
    --  # This works in macOS Catalina and 
    --  # macOS Big Sur and may need adjusting
    --  # for other versions of macOS.
    
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until ¬
        exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hi There. Thanks for you answer here. Do you have security concerns from selecting "Allow Javascript from Apple Events"?